# Javascript/Jquery Logic - Few Questions about Modal and .data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys I have a few questions so I'll get to it as best as I can.

I am using javascript and jquery along with ajax to pass json data to my database. I am also using Spring MVC to process the store/request data but that is not my concern.

I am using Metronic theme, and currently in the form wizard where student need to fill a form for application. I have trouble in using the Modal to get/pass data between the tables and the Modal, vice versa.

I have a few objectives that I want to accomplish and I have issues with them after trying a few approach.

1) Here is the screenshot and I will explain what I am to achieve and what issue I have.
[image]

When clicking the "Add new Owner" button, a modal should appear(you can see in below). Data inserted using the modal will populate in table below the button as the arrows shown.

[image]

So, in the "matrik No." field, it is a Select2 dropdown that will filter the id of the student as they type. and once the id has been selected, the fields from Name to Email including the student's photo will auto-populate.

When clicking the "add owner" button(in the modal), those data will be shown in the table on the first screenshot.

Here is my related codes for the modal and the buttons.

HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                        <h3 class="form-section">Owner Info</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <a class="btn green add-owner pull-left"
                                                data-toggle="modal" href="#large"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New Owner</a>
                                <table class="table borderless table-hover" id="tab_owner">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                                <th> Matrik No. </th>
                                                <th> Name</th>
                                                <th> IC No.</th>
                                                <th> Birth Place</th>
                                                <th> Faculty</th>
                                                <th> Phone No.</th>
                                                <th> Email</th>
                                                <th width="3%"></th>
                                                <th width="3%"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal fade bs-modal-lg" id="large" tabindex="-1"
                            role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                            aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Owner</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form id='frm'>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-10 center-block">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Matrik No. <span
                                                        class="required"> * </span></label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                                        <input name="matrik_number" class="form-control select2" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                                        <img name="student_photo" id="student_photo" alt=""
                                                            class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Name</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_name" id="student_name" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                            readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">IC Number</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_ic" id="student_ic" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                            readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Birth Place</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_birthplace" id="student_birthplace" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Faculty</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="faculty_name" id="faculty_name" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Study Year</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_studyyear" id="student_studyyear" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Phone No.</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_phoneno" id="student_phone" maxlength="11" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">E-Mail</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_emailadd" id="student_email" type="text" maxlength="50"
                                                            class="form-control">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Year Start
                                                        Business</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <div class="radio-list">
                                                            <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"
                                                                name="optionsRadios4" value="option1" /> 1
                                                            </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                                                type="radio" name="optionsRadios4" value="option2" />
                                                                2
                                                            </label> </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                                                type="radio" name="optionsRadios4" value="option3" />
                                                                3
                                                            </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                                                type="radio" name="optionsRadios4" value="option4" />
                                                                4
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <a class="btn green add-modal-owner" data-dismiss="modal">Add Owner</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

JS

```
        //tab2
        tab_owner.on('click', '.add-owner', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        tab_owner.on('click', '.del-owner', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('tr').html('');
        });

        tab_owner.on('click', '.edit-owner', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var m = $(this).closest('tr').find('.matrik').html();
            var n = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html();
            var i = $(this).closest('tr').find('.ic').html();
            var bp = $(this).closest('tr').find('.bp').html();
            var fac = $(this).closest('tr').find('.fac').html();
            var f = $(this).closest('tr').find('.fon').html();
            var e = $(this).closest('tr').find('.email').html();

            $('#matrik_number', large).val(m);
            $('#student_name', large).val(n);
            $('#student_ic', large).val(i);
            $('#student_birthplace', large).val(bp);
            $('#faculty_name', large).val(fac);
            $('#student_phone', large).val(f);
            $('#student_email', large).val(e);

            large.modal();
        });

        large.on('click', '.add-modal-owner', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var student_data = {
                    id:$('[name=matrik_number]').val(), 
                    phone:$("[name=student_phoneno]").val(), 
                    email:$("[name=student_emailadd]").val(),
                    optionradio4:$("[name=optionsRadios4]").val()
                };

            var show_studentdata = $("<tr>\n" +
                        "<td class='matrik'>" + $('[name=matrik_number]').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td class='name'>" + $('#student_name').val()+ "</td>\n" +
                        "<td class='ic'>" + $('#student_ic').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td class='bp'>" + $('#student_birthplace').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td class='fac'>" + $('#faculty_name').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td class='fon'>" + $('#student_phone').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td class='email'>" + $('#student_email').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm purple edit-owner pull-right'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i>Edit</a></td>" +
                        "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red del-owner pull-right'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i>Remove</a></td>" +
                        "</tr>\n");

            //insert modal data to tables/forms

    $('tbody',tab_owner).append(show_studentdata).data(student_data);

                //console.log(student_data);
                //console.log($('tr#C11A007').data());

                //clear all data upon close/save
                $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
                    $("input").val("");
                    $('[name=optionsRadios4]',form).each(function(){
                        $(this).prop('checked',false).uniform('refresh');
                    });
                    $('#student_photo').attr('src', '');
                    $("[name=matrik_number]").select2("val", "");
                });
        });
```

I managed to do the append() part when the add owner button is working. However I am having problem when I want to edit(how to call it back), and to validate the add owner button(inside modal) if the no input has been inserted.

This is the 3rd screenshot to show how the table looks like after adding the owners,

[image]

Marked as number 1, ignore it for now.

Marked as number 2, is the edit button. For now(if you are looking at my codes, I just use find() to get the html contents but I am sure there could be a better way? It will also create a duplicate data if I press "Edit" and correct some info, press Add Owner in the modal again.

I hope my explanation does not confuse those who are reading this. I have been stuck to this for about a week now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to edit a row in your table. But the code you have written would add a new row every time you will edit an existing record. That is because of the following line which creates a new row.

`$('tbody', tab_owner).append(show_studentdata).data(student_data);`

In order for you to be able to edit the row you need to replace the old row with the new one.

In `tab_owner.on()`, you have access to current `tr`. You can keep this in a global variable like

`selectedRow = $(this).closest('tr');`
(be sure to clean if afterwards)

Later, in `large.on()`, you can do the following

```
if (selectedRow && selectedRow.length) { // check if in edit mode
    selectedRow.replaceWith(show_studentdata).data(student_data);
  } else { // add mode
    $('tbody', tab_owner).append(show_studentdata).data(student_data);
  }
```

be sure to clear `selectedRow` in add

```
tab_owner.on('click', '.add-owner', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  selectedRow = null;
});
```

For the validation part, you can check for the conditions on `student_data` variable in `large.on()` and `return` in case of validation fail. like

```
if (student_data.email == "") {
    return;
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: unforturnately still didnt work. No errors in the console. all behaviours are still the same~ duplicates of data. I am still experimenting with some other ways but still no go. maybe you have other  ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: How about you make a fiddle and we can see what's really wrong